# Jquery - Animate Background position with easing

Tags: jquery, mousemove, easing

I am trying to animate a background on mousemove with some easing using jquery animate. But cant figure out how to stop the queuing of the animation and have the animation "follow" the mouse around

HTML:

```
Animate Background<br />
<div id="animateme"></div>​
```

JS:

```
$("#animateme").bind('mousemove', function(e) {

    $(this).animate({
        'background-position-x': e.pageX,
        'background-position-y': e.pageY
    }, 100, 'swing');

});​
```

I have set up a jsfiddle to hopefully show what i mean
http://jsfiddle.net/KunZ4/1/

Hover over the top image and you can see the background animation follows the mouse. But i want to add some easing to this, so it follows the mouse a bit smoother.

Using jquery animation seems to queue, but i want the animation to kind of catch up to the mouse on a bit of a delay when mouse movement is stopped.

I am wanting to achieve this without the use of UI or Plugins.

Hopefully that makes some kind of sense

Comment: The top one is _pretty_ smooth to me...

Comment: Yes - but i want the background to "catch up" to the mousemovement

So there is a delay in the moving.

Comment: http://www.chromazone-imaging.co.uk/flashindex.html

If you look at that website - Same type of effect but not jquery

Comment: Lol that was made with flash :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found something that worked for me, for anyone else looking for this

http://jsfiddle.net/KunZ4/6/

The easing can be adjusted by changing the duration

```
$.easing.smoothmove = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
 }; 


$("#animateme").bind('mousemove', function(e){

 $(this).animate({
   'background-position-x': e.pageX,
   'background-position-y': e.pageY
 }, {queue:false,duration:200,easing:'smoothmove'});

 });
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Is there a way to make the background go back to its original position after the mouse has stopped hovering the div?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `stop(true)` before the `.animate` function:

```
$("#animateme").bind('mousemove', function(e) {

    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        'background-position-x': e.pageX,
        'background-position-y': e.pageY
    }, 100, 'swing');

});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/KunZ4/4/

Comment: Yea - I tried that, but it doesn't really give a smooth effect when you move the mouse around fast. Appreciate the help though

Answer (score 0):

Developed, (when mouse moving in BODY):
http://jsfiddle.net/hX22a/

```
$.easing.smoothmove = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
}; $("body").bind('mousemove', function(e){
$("#animateme").animate({
'background-position-x': e.pageX,
'background-position-y': e.pageY
}, {queue:false,duration:200,easing:'smoothmove'});
});
```